# Android Livedata with RxJava Single not work in Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room, android-livedata

I used Room and RxJava `Single` with Livedata, it doesn't work.
I tried in two ways. I don't know why the second one works and why the first one doesn't.

(1) get List by Single -> not work
(2) get List by Livedata -> work

#### (1) get List by Single

**DAO**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface DiaryDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Review")
    fun getAllReview() : Single<List<Review>>    // <- See the return type!
}
```

**ViewModel**
*I used Repository pattern* (The return type of dao and the return type of repository are same)

```kotlin
    private val _reviewData = MutableLiveData<List<Review>>()
    val reviewData : LiveData<List<Review>>
        get() = _reviewData

    fun getAllReview(){
        addDisposable(repo.getAllReview()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                _reviewData.value=it
            },{
                Log.d(TAG, it.localizedMessage)
            })
        )
    }
```

**Fragment**

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.getAllReview()
        viewModel.reviewData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

It works when the fragment is created, but the data is not updated when it is changed.

#### (2) get List by Livedata

**DAO**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface DiaryDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Review")
    fun getAllReview() : LiveData<List<Review>>    // <- See the return type!
}
```

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
    private val _reviewData : LiveData<List<Review>> = repo.getAllReview()
    val reviewData : LiveData<List<Review>>
        get() = _reviewData
```

**Fragment**

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.reviewData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            // it works!
        }

    }
```

It works well when the data changes.

##### Why should I use the second method? Is there any way to make the first method work?

I look forward to your advice.

Please let me know if there is any additional code you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

`Single<List<Review>>` is a single operation, it either returns data or it doesn't, and it only does it once. What you want is `Flowable<List<Review>>`. This will allow you to subscribe to the database and watch for changes, when a change happens it will report it to its subscribers.

Comment: If I call `viewModel.getAllReview()` from `onResume()`, it returns `Single` one more, I wonder why it doesn't work.. TT

Comment: `OnResume` of your `Fragment` or the containing `Activity`?

Comment: In Fragment...!

Comment: Shot in the dark but `onPause`  clear  your composite disposable.

Comment: OMG I didn't think of the concept of disposable...
As you said, I dispose it and it works well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also from what I know Singles don't need Disposables, as they are guaranteed to complete either through data retrieval or error. Meaning they automatically dispose of themselves. `Maybe` and `Flowable` types don't those so thats when you would need a disposable for clean up.